# iis 7 Error 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: php, iis-7, windows-server-2008

I have a php website whose server is iis 7. When the website is on a Server 2008 32-bit platform, the error is thrown. If I move the page to another directory, the error follows. Yet on my developmentserver, a 64 bit machine, with the very same code, there is no error. I am perplexed and looking for solutions.

Comment: There's only one solution - check error log.

Comment: 2 solutions. use a Linux based web server (sorry, couldn't resist), but yes, logs are a good thing©